Library issue in android studio
Some Libraries are not working.
Android-Image-Slider and some other libraries are not getting implemented while build. I have updated spec and versions, so there is no issue with that and code.
This is the snippet
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

This is what I get during build:

Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/smarteist/autoimageslider/1.4.0/autoimageslider-1.4.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

This is a partial build output with the error in question:
9: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.4.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/smarteist/autoimageslider/1.4.0/autoimageslider-1.4.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/smarteist/autoimageslider/1.4.0/autoimageslider-1.4.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
   > Could not find com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.6.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.7.3.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.7.3.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.7.3.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:2.7.3.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.7.3.
     Required by:
         project :app


Please [edit] the question and provide a [mre]. The settings.gradle you provided works fine as it is, please provide enough code for us to actually reproduce the issue. And while you're at it, please update the question title to be more descriptive about the specific problem you have.

Your problem is that you are still using parts if the old artifact name as it was published on JCenter, but Jitpack bases on URLs.
Looking at the Gradle error message you seem to use as dependency
com.github.smarteist.autoimageslider:1.4.0 (and important detail that is missing in your question).
But the GitHub project has the URL https://github.com/smarteist/Android-Image-Slider which means the last part should be Android-Image-Slider and not autoimageslider.

which is also pretty clear when you look at the jitpack page: https://jitpack.io/#smarteist/Android-Image-Slider/1.4.0
